# how to open multiple file from single file which is having list of files in python and how to do processing on them?

Tags: python, file-handling

i am having single file called bar.txt which is having list of files as follows,

bar.txt -

1.txt

2.txt

3.txt

each file inside bar.txt having some similar contents.

1.txt  -

spec = sadasdsad

2.txt -

spec = dddddd

3.txt -

spec = ppppppppp

how can i open all files inside bar.txt and extract the data from all file and store in other file called foo.txt ?

in foo.txt i want extracted data mentioned below,

foo.txt -

spec = sadasdsad

spec = dddddd

spec = ppppppppp

```
 outfile = open('bar.txt', "rw")
 outfile_1 = open('foo.txt', "w")
     for f in outfile:
        f=f.rstrip()
        lines = open(f,'rw')
        lines = re.findall(".*SPEC.*\\n",lines)
        outfile_1.write(lines)
 outfile.close()
```

Comment: Why use python? bash would be faster according to me

Comment: actually this small spinet is part of my script , and my script is in python

Comment: First, try using different variable for different things. You assign multiple different things to one `f` variable. First its single line on outfile, then it's the same line striped, then it's another opened file, and finally you try to use the same f variable outside of it's scope (outside `for` loop).

Comment: in bar.txt , all lines are coming with \n(new line char) because of which i am getting fie/dir not exist so that why i did rstrip() .

Comment: as you said if i do try with different variables i am getting                                                 error return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code is almost correct. I guess you messed everything up by using `f` variable for almost everything. So you assign multiple different things to one f variable. First its single line on outfile, then it's the same line striped, then it's another opened file, and finally you try to use the same f variable outside of it's scope (outside for loop). Try using different variables for all theses beings.

Also make sure you have correct indents (e.g `for` loop indent is incorrect in your example), and not that regex `findall` works on string, not file-like object, so second argument of `findall` should be `contentfile.read()`.

```
infile = open('bar.txt', "r")
outfile = open('foo.txt', "w")
for f in infile:
    name=f.rstrip()
    contentfile = open(name,'rw')
    #all_matches= re.findall(<define your real pattern here>,contentfile.read())
    result = 0 #do something with your all_matches
    outfile.write(result)
    contentfile.close()
outfile.close()
infile.close()
```

Comment: hey after doing outfile.writelines(result) insted of outfile.write(result) it is working..

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```py
infile = open('bar.txt', "r")
outfile = open('foo.txt', "w")
line = infile.readline()

while line:
    f = line.rstrip()
    contents_file = open(f,'rw')
    contents = contents_file.read()
    outfile.write(contents)
    f = infile.readline()
 
outfile.close()
```

Comment: thans for help i will try this